# UWP C# Handling "X" (close) of AccountsSettingsPane

Tags: c#, uwp

I've got some code to show `[AccountsSettingsPane]`[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.AccountsSettingsPane) but I can't seem to figure out how to handle the case when the users close the pane.

I can't find any code samples to do this.

[image]

Comment: It is documented in the MSDN article, somewhat poorly, you are supposed to use the WebAccountCommand or WebAccountProviderCommand command to invoke the dialog.  They have an Invoked property, that lets you run code when the user completes the dialog.

Comment: @HansPassant, I think I've got the part to handle `WebAccountCommand` or `WebAccountProviderCommand` It's the handling of the closing of the pane that I can't figure out. I want to force a log-in and close the app (perhaps display a message first) if the user doesn't log-in (closed the settings pane).

Comment: You'll surely need to make it obvious in your UI, perhaps with a giant "Login" button, that doesn't disappear until your Invoked handler gets invoked.

Comment: What I'm asking is a step beyond that already. This dialog is already on screen. I can handle when the users pick an option under "Use this account" or "Use a different account" I'm not sure how to handle when the user clicks on the "X"

Answer (score 0):

In your App, when you request a token from a web account provider or start an authentication operation asynchronously, you will call a request or authentication method to do that.

We use the code of the official document [Web Account Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager) as an example.

The `GetMsaTokenAsync` method will be called before user clicks the "X" and will return a `WebTokenRequestStatus.UserCancel` in `result.ResponseStatus` if the user click "X":

```
private async void GetMsaTokenAsync(WebAccountProviderCommand command)
{
    WebTokenRequest request = new WebTokenRequest(command.WebAccountProvider, "wl.basic");
    WebTokenRequestResult result = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request);
    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        // TODO
    }
    if (result.ResponseStatus== WebTokenRequestStatus.UserCancel)
    {
        // User click the "X"
    }
}
```

When you start an authentication operation, there also is a `WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel` result in the `WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus`. You can check your code to find the corresponding API to handle the case when the users close the pane.

Comment: I tried that per your suggestion above, but it doesn't get to `GetMsaTokenAsync` because no option was clicked. The user clicks on the X immediately on the `AccountsSettingsPane` after `AccountsSettingsPane.Show();`

Comment: @CarloMendoza Could you provide a simple sample to see how your app goes? In my test using the official document sample, it will call the `GetMsaTokenAsync` method everytime displaying the `AccountsSettingsPane`.

Comment: @CarloMendoza Whether your code will get into the else if statement `result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.UserCancel` when   the user clicks on the X immediately?

Comment: It never gets into `GetMsaTokenAsyncTest` so it never gets to that part. As far as I see, `GetMsaTokenAsyncTest` only gets invoked when the user picks an option--like in my screenshot, picking the Microsoft account entry, BUT If the user doesn't pick anything and closes the pane, nothing happens--the pane just goes away.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce?

Comment: I tried with this part of code but can not run the code as a project. It will be better if you can provide a simple complete project to try the situation of clicking the x immediately.

Comment: I just realized that this may have been by design. I changed my layout to have a page that only shows a "sign in" button and users won't get past that unless they follow through.

Comment: Yes, as what we can see, there is no an event for closing the `AccountsSettingsPane`. We are just trying to find a way to handle the click "x"  event.

Comment: Instead of calling `AccountsSettingsPane.Show()`, call `AccountsSettingsPane.ShowManageAccountsAsync()` and use the completion of the `IAsyncAction` to infer that the pane was closed.